# Redirect output with ">>" doesnt always work?

Tags: redirect, stdout

i have such problem. When i use command for 7zip:

```
7za a -t7z file.7z file.iso
```

i see in console dynamically changing output like this:

```
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive file.7z

Compressing  file.iso    12%
```

When i redirect output to file with command:

```
7za a -t7z file.7z file.iso >> file.txt
```

Im just getting final message:

```
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive file.7z

Compressing  file.iso

Everything is Ok
```

Why? I want all messages. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's common behavior to disable logging meant only for human consumption when the destination is not a TTY, at least by default. (Beyond that, make sure the content you want isn't on stderr rather than stdout).

Answer (score 0):

it all is ok, I'm using exactly the same 7zip version under current stable debian 7.1 64bit.
7zip detects, stdout is assigned to terminal or not. when not to terminal, this in the background use option -bd  , disable percentage indicator. developer assumes that you read log post factum, and do not analize output on the fly.
unfortunately it is not possible switch on percentages on the file. you can only switch off percentages on the screen.

what for you need % in log   file.txt   ?